# Simple AngularJs custom directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to AngularJS and have a very simple sample that is not working.  I am hoping someone could tell me what I am missing.  It is supposed to change the color on mouse-enter and change the html when clicked:

http://plnkr.co/edit/fQ5nejywl1taPSpZuBVv?p=preview

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.0-beta.5" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div my-dom-directive>Click me!!</div>
 </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

(function(){

   var directive = function() {
     return {
       link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
         element.bind('click', function() {
         element.html('Clicked I am!');
        });

        element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
           element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
        });

        element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
           element.css('background-color', 'white');
        });
      }  
    };
  };

  angular.module('app').directive('myDomDirective', directive);
})
```

If I do not use a self-invoking method to add the directive, it works fine.

Thanks.

Comment: You missed function invocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking your self invoking function. I.e () at the end.

Or an alternative:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);

(function(module){

   var directive = function() {
     return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
        element.html('Clicked I am!');
        });

        element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
           element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
        });

        element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
           element.css('background-color', 'white');
        });
      }  
   };
  };

  module.directive('myDomDirective', directive);
})(app);
```

The second approach passes in your module as a parameter to you self-invoking function.

Answer (score 1):

You are not invoking the self-invoking function.  You need '()' at the end of that function definition to invoke it as you are merely wrapping it in brackets at the moment.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

(function(){

   var directive = function() {
     return {
       link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
         element.bind('click', function() {
         element.html('Clicked I am!');
        });

        element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
           element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
        });

        element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
           element.css('background-color', 'white');
        });
      }  
    };
  };

  // you could just use closure here as the app variable is available
  app.directive('myDomDirective', directive);
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the function that is wrapping the directive (I don't see a point in having it) and also notice how the directive is created (use **app**.directive(...) directly):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

var directive = function() {

    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.html('Clicked I am!');
            });

            element.bind('mouseenter', function() {
                element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
            });

            element.bind('mouseleave', function() {
                element.css('background-color', 'white');
            });
        }
    };
  };

  app.directive('myDomDirective', directive);
```

OR unless you have a special reason do declare the directive separately something like this will be even better:

```
app.directive('myDomDirective',function() {
    return {
        ...
    }
});
```

Comment: According to this article, it is a useful pattern in order to keep things out of the global scope:  http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-i-the-fundamentals, but I am not sure if it makes any difference in this case.